# Javascript validations are not working in event listener

Tags: javascript, validation, event-listener

I'm working on a beginner coding project.

I've added in validations for each question in my form, and they seem to be checking out. I also added in a final validation button that should read "thank you for your order" if everything has validated (which it looks like it has) but it's not working.

I tried add in an event listener per recommendation of chatgpt, but it's still not working.

I have a github here

https://github.com/allisonmw123/Coding-class-validation-not-working

```js
    function areAllValid() {
    var isValid = true;
    if (!validateFullName()) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (!validateBread()) { // Add this line
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (!validateEmailAndType()) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (!validateinfo()) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (!validatePhone()) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (!validateCheese()) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (!validateMeats()) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (!validateVeggie()) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
    }

   var previewbtn = document.querySelector("#previewbtn");

    previewbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (areAllValid()) {
      document.querySelector("#previewFormData").innerHTML = "<h4>Thank you for your order!    </h4>";
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#previewFormData").innerHTML = "<h4>Please finalize your selections.</h4>";
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'm taking an online coding class for fun, to add some additional skills to my resume, but I'm very close to giving up hah... this is very frustrating

Comment: What happens instead? Do you get the _"Please finalize your selections"_ message or does nothing apparently happen? Use your browser's dev-tools console to check for errors

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to `return` the value from the `function`! especially `validateBread, validateMeats, validateCheese and validateVeggie`!

You should add return lines in the end of function definition like `return isCheeseChecked` which will make your functions look like following!

```js
function validateBread() {
    var breadOptions = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="bread"]');
    var isBreadChecked = false;
  
    for (var i = 0; i < breadOptions.length; i++) {
      if (breadOptions[i].checked) {
        isBreadChecked = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  
    if (isBreadChecked) {
      document.querySelector("#feedbbread").innerHTML = "Valid";
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#feedbbread").innerHTML = "Please select a meat option.";
    }

    return isBreadChecked
  }

function validateMeats() {
    var meatsOptions = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="meats"]');
    var isMeatsChecked = false;
  
    for (var i = 0; i < meatsOptions.length; i++) {
      if (meatsOptions[i].checked) {
        isMeatsChecked = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  
    if (isMeatsChecked) {
      document.querySelector("#feedbmeats").innerHTML = "Valid";
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#feedbmeats").innerHTML = "Please select a meat option.";
    }

    return isMeatsChecked
  }

function validateCheese() {
    var cheeseOptions = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="cheese"]');
    var isCheeseChecked = false;
  
    for (var i = 0; i < cheeseOptions.length; i++) {
      if (cheeseOptions[i].checked) {
        isCheeseChecked = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  
    if (isCheeseChecked) {
      document.querySelector("#feedbcheese").innerHTML = "Valid";
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#feedbcheese").innerHTML = "Please select a cheese option.";
    }

    return isCheeseChecked
  }

  function validateVeggie() {
    var veggieOptions = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="veggie"]');
    var isVeggieChecked = false;
  
    for (var i = 0; i < veggieOptions.length; i++) {
      if (veggieOptions[i].checked) {
        isVeggieChecked = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  
    if (isVeggieChecked) {
      document.querySelector("#feedbveggie").innerHTML = "Valid";
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#feedbveggie").innerHTML = "Please select a veggie option.";
    }

    return isVeggieChecked
  }
```

You can read more about `return` on [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) or [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp)!